# how to share a javascript websocket instance with multiple html files

Tags: javascript, python, flask, websocket

I am using websockets in javascript and python flask.

I have a websocket server to which i connect my webpage using javascript websockets. The "/" contains a form that contain the ip address of the websocket server, and "/connectToServer" route will establish a websocket connection with the server.

Now, I will have routes from this webpage like, /details, /profile. I need to use the same instance of the websocket in all my routes. How do i do it?

P.S. I do not intend to use the websocket client api in python. I need to do it in javascript only.

Answer (score 0):

You would need something to make your page persistent.

Client-side libraries such as [Angular](https://angularjs.org/) or [Vue](https://vuejs.org/) (just two random examples) will do the job.

However you should look into a tutorial or something since its not very straightforward

Comment: thank you very much. @Alvaro Carvajal Nakosmai. your response led me to this blog,
http://tavendo.com/blog/post/websocket-persistent-connections/

Comment: I would recommend you reading a little about vue.js its very simple and you can achieve great things with it